# Android Studio or Gradle not compiling classes generated by dagger

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, dagger

I have one Android library that I created using dagger for dependency injection ('br.com.estudio89:syncing:1.0-SNAPSHOT'). The dependency manager I used while creating this library was Maven.

Now I am working on a different project where I need to use this library, but this time I am using Gradle for dependency management.

What is happening now is that the classes that were generated by dagger in my library are not being compiled into my new app, causing a NoClassDefFoundError like so:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: br.com.estudio89.syncing.injection.AppContextModule$$ModuleAdapter$ProvideAppContextProvidesAdapter
```

I am also getting these errors:

```
05-03 01:26:48.147  30634-30634/br.com.estudio89.rhmais E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'dagger.internal.Binding', referenced from method dagger.internal.FailoverLoader.getAtInjectBinding
05-03 01:26:48.155  30634-30634/br.com.estudio89.rhmais E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'dagger.internal.SetBinding', referenced from method dagger.ObjectGraph$StandardBindings.<init>
05-03 01:26:48.171  30634-30634/br.com.estudio89.rhmais E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'dagger.internal.Binding', referenced from method dagger.internal.BindingsGroup.get
05-03 01:26:48.171  30634-30634/br.com.estudio89.rhmais E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'dagger.internal.Binding', referenced from method dagger.internal.BindingsGroup.put
05-03 01:26:48.171  30634-30634/br.com.estudio89.rhmais E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'br.com.estudio89.syncing.injection.AppContextModule$$ModuleAdapter$ProvideAppContextProvidesAdapter', referenced from method br.com.estudio89.syncing.injection.AppContextModule$$ModuleAdapter.getBindings
05-03 01:26:48.175  30634-30634/br.com.estudio89.rhmais E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'br.com.estudio89.syncing.injection.DataSyncHelperModule$$ModuleAdapter$ProvideCustomTransactionManagerProvidesAdapter', referenced from method br.com.estudio89.syncing.injection.DataSyncHelperModule$$ModuleAdapter.getBindings
```

You can see my build.gradle file below:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.2'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {

    apt 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2'
    apt 'br.com.estudio89:syncing:1.0-SNAPSHOT'

    compile (
        'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.3',
        'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.5.2',
        'com.joanzapata.android:android-iconify:1.0.9',
        'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.0.1',
        'com.github.bluejamesbond:textjustify-android:2.1.0',

        'br.com.estudio89:syncing:1.0-SNAPSHOT',
        'br.com.estudio89:push_messaging:1.0-SNAPSHOT',

        'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0',
        'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0',
        'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0',

    )
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.2.1'
}
```

I don't know if this is a problem with Gradle or Android Studio but I tried everything I could think of and couldn't find a solution... For the current project I am not actually using dagger but I added it to the gradle file in hope it would work... Any help will be greatly appreciated!